# How to handle WiFi to Mobile network switch programatically?

Tags: android, networking, wifi, 3g

Right now, I am having application which works with WiFi, but while I am going to mobile providers network my application does not working. I have maintained one background service which checks for network, but im not getting how to handle network switch WiFi to Mobile and Mobile to WiFi? I am not getting how to handle WiFi to mobile network switch because already WiFi is enabled and I am not in WiFi coverage area; in this situation I want to get switched to mobile network automatically and vice-versa. My approach is as follows which is not working:

```
String networkStatus = "disconnected";
            int netType = 0;
            try{
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if(connectivityManager != null ){
                    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                    if(networkInfo != null){
                        netType = networkInfo.getType();
                        Log.d("Log", "connetion is available");
                    }else {
                        Log.d("Log", "connetion is  not available");
                        return networkStatus;
                    }

                //  if(networkInfo.isAvailable()){  // Old one
if(networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected()){  // New change added here
                        if(netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                            {}
                        else if(netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE )
                            {}
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Log", "checkNetworkConnection" + e.toString());
            return networkStatus;
        }
```

Already I have read many posts over hear still not getting idea. Can anyone give me any idea or url where I can get same approach to implement?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
String networkStatus = "disconnected";
            int netType = 0;
            try{
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if(connectivityManager != null ){
                    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                    if(networkInfo != null){
                        netType = networkInfo.getType();
                        Log.d("Log", "connetion is available");
                    }else {
                        Log.d("Log", "connetion is  not available");
                        return networkStatus;
                    }

                //  if(networkInfo.isAvailable()){  // Old one
if(networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected()){  // New change added here
                        if(netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                            {}
                        else if(netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE )
                            {}
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Log", "checkNetworkConnection" + e.toString());
            return networkStatus;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

http://thiranjith.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/how-to-monitor-network-connectivity-in-android/

Hope this will help you..

Comment: This should be a comment