# How to know change in network connection in android

Tags: android, networking

How to know whether there is any network connection switch or network connection lost in my application.

Comment: what protocol you are using? in Socket it will be easy to know that connection is lost, in Http there will be different way

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `ConnectivityManager` in Android:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo net = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if(net != null && net.isConnected()) {
    // we have connection
}
```

Edit: Checking for internet connection requires some permissions as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer my post over here for network switch and checking connection:
(Note: I have posted answer below question in that post)

[How to handle WiFi to Mobile network switch programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205720/how-to-handle-wifi-to-mobile-network-switch-programatically)

You have to add some permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```