# How to detect IP address change?

Tags: android

My app uses a native browser (webview), which is used to browse a certain website. While browsing the website, if the user switches from mobile data(2G, 3G) to wifi or vice-versa, there is a change in IP. When that happens the browser stops receiving any data from the server (website).

Does anyone know how to handle this situation. I was thinking of somehow detecting this IP change and re-establishing a connection with the server. Would this be a good solution. If yes, then how do I re-establish the connection between the native browser and the server?

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be as easy as refreshing the page on an connection type change?

Comment: How do I detect a "connection type change?" Refreshing doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you refresh the WebView, it should automagically use the new Connection type. When to refresh the webview? Polling for IP changes would work, but I'd do some hard Googling for a "conectionChange" event of some kind

Comment: I've figured out how to detect connection change from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205720/how-to-handle-wifi-to-mobile-network-switch-programatically However, refresh doesn't work? Any ideas why?

Comment: Probably because when the WebView is created it inializes its networking stuff. Destroy and recreate the webview on change.

Comment: I tried destroying the webview and the re-creating it, but even that doesn't work. `webview.destroy(); webview = null(); webview = new WebView(this); ... `